# How to merge after backout Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I did commit with merge, after that I did backout in main branch in order to revert last merge.
After some time I need to merge branch, but mercurial says that abort: merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect

But in develop branch I don't see my changes from other branch.

Answer (score 0):

Merge only picks up things that are new since the last merge.  For instance:

```
default:   *------------?
            \          /
develop:     o--o--o--o
```

Each `o` represents some commit.  We started with the default branch (named `default`) with just one commit, the one marked `*` instead of `o` here.  Then we made a `develop` branch starting with that same first commit, and did some work.

Once the work was ready, we went back to the `default` branch and used `hg merge`.  This proposed making a new commit, `?`.  It did so by looking back to `*`—the commit that we had in common between `default` and `develop`—and looking at what we did on the two branches, and combining them.

We did nothing on `default`, so the combining was easy.  Mercurial was able to just take everything we did on `develop` and put it all into `default`.  Let's fill in the merge as a real commit now:

```
default:   o------------*
            \          /
develop:     o--o--o--o
```

Notice that I've moved the `*`.  It's now the new merge.  This is the most recent commit that links the two branches.

Meanwhile, `hg backout` makes a new commit that undoes a previous commit.  Specifically you're asking to back out the merge.  Let's draw that:

```
default:   o------------*--u
            \          /
develop:     o--o--o--o
```

This new commit is sort of like the antimatter version of the merge, in terms of changes made anyway.  Everything in `default` goes back to the way it was before the merge.  So I used the letter `u` (for "undo") instead of the usual round `o` dot for a more typical commit.

Where's the latest common commit on the two branches, though?  The answer should be obvious: it's still `*`.

Now you ask Mercurial to merge again.  It finds the changes in `develop` since the merge—*and there aren't any*.  There is no new work to merge!

Suppose we check out `develop` again and make some *new* commits:

```
default:   o------------*--u
            \          /
develop:     o--o--o--o------o--o
```

*Now* we can `hg merge develop` into `default` again, to pick up the changes from the two *new* commits.  But the changes you *undid*, with commit `u` (the backout commit), are still un-done.  We'll only pick up the changes from the *new* (since the merge) commits on `develop`, and we *keep* the changes made (since the merge) on `default`, which is to say, the `u` undo changes:

```
default:   o------------o--u------*
            \          /         /
develop:     o--o--o--o------o--o
```

If you want all those changes back, you can simple back out the backout.  That is, any time before or after adding the new commits on `develop`, and even before or after merging those new commits, you can undo the undo.  Let's turn the `u` upside down into a "redo" and see how that looks, if we insert it before the next merge:

```
default:   o------------o--u--n-----*
            \          /           /
develop:     o--o--o--o--------o--o
```

In other words, commit `u` (the `hg backout`) un-did the *changes* from the merge.  It does not, and cannot, actually make the merge *not happen*.  So to *re-obtain* the changes from the merge, you have to undo the undo, which is our `n` here.